# How to alter default value of select in webform

Tags: 7, webforms

Using drupal 7 and Webform (both up2date), how can I alter the default value of a "Select options" field?

I tried to do this:

```
function mymodul_webform_component_render_alter (&$element, &$component) {
if( $element['#type'] == 'select' && 
      $element['#title'] == 'field1' ) {
$element['#default_value'] = 'bar,foo';}
}
```

But it's not working...

I can make it work with a single default value if I set the field to "Listbox", what I don't want. But I still can bypass this "if" statement... But still can't set the default value to multiple choices

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple selects use an array for the default value:

```
$element['#default_value'] = array('foo', 'bar');
```